# Saving Access file to SharePoint with code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a standard Access Database saved on SharePoint. My organization uses SharePoint, but I only have standard access to areas particular to my department. (I cannot create or link a web based database to SharePoint with my access level.)

In my Access file, I have a form that saves its data to the table - locally - when I hit the submit button.

The ribbon below appears and if clicked, transfers the whole Access file to the SharePoint storage location, but only if that button is clicked. Otherwise it only saves a local copy.

[image]

Is there a way I can automate a network/SharePoint save location in code so the user doesn't have to remember to press that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of trying to figure this out - there's a simpler solution.

Save the file as an exectuable - accde instead of accdb. Not only does it not ask to run the macros every time, but it saves automatically to SharePoint.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.